# how to fix error of empty $_POST['name']

Tags: php

I want to have a form with php. but for many hours I'm involved an error and the error is when $_POST=['name'] wants to be checked empty or not it is empty.
When I check the database the row is white and nothing is there.
for checking if the $_POST is empty or not I print word 'empty' to be determined it's empty and it will be printed 'empty';
where is my mistake is it related to database mysql or not just in code?
please help me I got confused and bored.
this is whole of my codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>form</title>
<link href="addContact.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$name = "";
$nameErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    echo 'empty';
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
    echo 'full';
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }


  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "abc";
  $password = "abc";
  $dbname = "abc";

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
  $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO abc (firstname)
    VALUES ('$name')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I don't quite get it, but what about trying to do `if ($_POST['name'] == '')` ?

Comment: What is the version of PHP you are using?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to have any syntax errors, but it still tries to create a database record even if `name` is blank - which I assume is logically not what you want to do. In any case, I'd ensure you have error checking enabled - add `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` to the top of your file.

Comment: @cse php version is 5.6.25. is it ok?

Comment: Also, note that `"INSERT INTO abc (firstname) VALUES ('$name')"` is vulnerable to SQL injection. You are using PDO, which allows you to write secure SQL statements with [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in use of `empty()`

You can use it on *variables* not on *values*.

See here for [PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

To check this, first save it in another variable and then check:

```
$tempVal = $_POST["name"];
if (empty($tempVal))
```

Comment: Note that this is the case for PHP versions <= 5.4

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple example

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name."; 
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

i suggest this:
[Understanding $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](https://guardianhost.com/myaccount/knowledgebase/31/Understanding-SERVERPHPSELF-PHPSELF-and-other-bits-of-PHP.html)

Comment: 123 thank you for your quick response, but I understood after click on submit the condition of if is not true, because it doesn't print 'User Has submitted the form and entered this name'. where is the problem?

Comment: @AmirGh - Since the form is posting back to the same URL it's possible to completely remove the `action` attribute.